# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm trying to write an SQL query but when I try to save it throws me an incorrect syntax error.
Here's the query:

```
(
@top int,
@bottom int
)

AS
        SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT top (@bottom - @top + 1) *
            FROM (SELECT top (@bottom) *
                  FROM    tblPlayers INNER JOIN
                          tblPosition ON tblPlayers.IDPosition = tblPosition.IDPosition INNER JOIN
                          tblTeams ON tblPlayers.IDTeam = tblTeams.IDTeam
                  ORDER BY (PPG DESC, APG DESC, RPG DESC)
                 )
            ORDER BY PPG ASC, APG ASC, RPG ASC
             )      
        ORDER BY PPG DESC, APG DESC, RPG DESC
    RETURN
```

The problem is with the most inner ORDER BY. Without it's brackets it gives an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. With the brackets the error is incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'. 
I'm out of ideas. The syntax seems fine to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PLease tell us what **concrete** database you're using - use the `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server` tags - or specify what else you're using (SQL is just the **query language** - not a product). ALso - this is not a complete code snippet - is this the body of a stored procedure? Of a CTE? Please post something **complete** - not just a few lines out of the middle of something....

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query needs table aliases, which may be part or all of the problem.  In addition, you should list the columns explicitly in the innermost subquery, because there are duplicate names:

```
    SELECT t.*
    FROM (SELECT top (@bottom - @top + 1) t.*
        FROM (SELECT top (@bottom) co1, col2, col3, . . .
              FROM    tblPlayers INNER JOIN
                      tblPosition ON tblPlayers.IDPosition = tblPosition.IDPosition INNER JOIN
                      tblTeams ON tblPlayers.IDTeam = tblTeams.IDTeam
              ORDER BY PPG DESC, APG DESC, RPG DESC
             ) t
        ORDER BY PPG ASC, APG ASC, RPG ASC
         ) t   
    ORDER BY PPG DESC, APG DESC, RPG DESC
```